# What's the easiest way to pick a facet in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I want to find out which facet is under the mouse cursor in an OpenGL application. Using the selection buffer seems quite inaccurate to me. Are there other solutions?

Comment: You might want to edit that to facet - otherwise it sounds like you want to do (human) face recognition.

Comment: Personally, I'd say "face" is a much much more common term than facet in 3D OpenGL development.

Comment: To people who don't know OpenGL "facet" seems clearer. People who know OpenGL will understand both. So I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @mdm: I've been using OpenGL for 15+ years, and I have no idea what a "facet" is.

Comment: Why not just call it a polygon face? Or Surface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it manually, using ray intersection. Use your camera matrix (if not explicit, you can query it from OpenGL), use it to generate a picking ray in world space, and see whether it intersects your particular face or not. Sort intersections on depth (t), and you have the closest face under the cursor.

Depending on your data structure (hierarchy, etc) and size this could be either really slow or really efficient.

Comment: How this is different than using selection buffer of a very small size?

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm going with this. It's more accurate than using selection buffer, can easily be ported to DirectX and although my scene is small enough to use the coloring technique using a picking ray seems like the only way if the scene is large (i.e. using a scene graph and/or BVH).

Comment: @artificalidiot - it's API-independent, and allows you to completely separate rendering and picking (which can be nice). However, if you use OpenGL constructs like point_size and line_width and want the picking to be visually correct, using the selection buffer can be more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

A common trick is to paint each facet in a different color (simply 0x000001 to n) render offscreen and get the color under the mouse point.

Comment: Be careful of dithering, blending, fog, lightning... basically anything that can remotely affect the colour of your polygons if you really want to use this technique. One option is drastically reducing number of colors and making them sufficiently different.

Comment: Enabled antialiasing will also spoil the picked color when two objects intersect.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at [this section](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm) of the OpenGL FAQ.